# Animate UICollectionView cell size change and reposition surrounding cells

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

[image]

**Goal:**

To animate the change of a cell's height and reposition surrounding cells.

**Scenario:**

Some cells in a collection view load remote images. Initially, those cells are sized statically and an activity indicator is shown. After an image is loaded, it is added to its cell and the cell's height is changed to fit the photo.

**Notes:**

I am animating the cell's frame change with `animateWithDuration`. This works fine, except an increased cell size has it overlapping the cells below. I've blindly tried calling `collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout` after resizing the target cell and updating the size returned by `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` with no success.

Any suggestions? Thank you!

**Sample Code:**

https://github.com/juzzin/ResizeUICollectionViewCell/blob/master/ResizeUICollectionViewCell/FLOViewController.m

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Basically you need to do three steps

1.invalidate the collectionViewLayout

2.perform batch updates:

```
 ...
 //invalidate layout
[collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
    // make your cell at indexPath return a new size
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

}];
```

3.return the new size at `sizeForItemAtIndexpath`

Comment: Thank you Daniel. Appreciate your quick and succinct response. I posted some sample code and learned that performBatchUpdates calls invalidateLayout after animations complete. If explicitly called before performBatchUpdates, animations are skipped since the cell attributes are updated immediately. So, I believe you can skip the first step.

Comment: I know I'm not supposed to say thank you but I've been struggling with this for DAYS and the solution is so simple! THANKS!! Thanks @Justin too for the Github link, very helpful.